# Using Alias in Case Statement

Tags: sql, case, alias

I want to alias the case as Brutobedrag but i can't get it done.

```
SELECT     
    Invoices.InvoiceNr AS Factuurnummer, 
    case(Invoices.IsDebit)
        when 0 then -1*(Invoices.NetAmount + Invoices.BTW + COALESCE (Invoices.BPM, 0)) 
        else Invoices.NetAmount + Invoices.BTW + COALESCE (Invoices.BPM, 0)
    end 
from
    Brands INNER JOIN
    Invoices ON Brands.Id = Invoices.Brand INNER JOIN
    SalesPersons ON Invoices.SalesPerson = SalesPersons.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Payments ON Invoices.Id = Payments.InvoiceId

where
    Invoices.InvoiceDate > '2011-12-31'

group by
    Invoices.InvoiceNr,
    Invoices.NetAmount,
    invoices.BTW,
    invoices.BPM,
    Invoices.IsDebit
```

Comment: What happens when you try?  Also, what is the purpose of the group by clause when you are not selecting any aggregates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case when Invoices.IsDebit = 0 
     then -1*(Invoices.NetAmount + Invoices.BTW + COALESCE (Invoices.BPM, 0)) 
     else Invoices.NetAmount + Invoices.BTW + COALESCE (Invoices.BPM, 0)
end as Brutobedrag
```

Answer (score 0):

WHEN ITS 'BC'

SELECT ( CASE  'BC' WHEN 'BC' THEN 1 WHEN 'AC' THEN 4
                                    WHEN 'CL' THEN 3
                                   ELSE ' ' END )
                                UNION  (SELECT (CASE  'BC'  WHEN 'BC' THEN 2
                                  ELSE ' ' END))
                                UNION  (SELECT (CASE  'BC'  WHEN 'BC' THEN 22
                                   ELSE ' ' END))
                                 UNION  (SELECT (CASE  'BC'  WHEN 'BC' THEN 24
                                  ELSE ' ' END))
                                 UNION  (SELECT (CASE  'BC'  WHEN 'BC' THEN 5
                                  ELSE ' ' END))

ANS:1
2
5
22
24

IT WILL BE USE FULL TO GET MULTIPLE VALUES WITH SINGLE CONDITION IN CASE